# mongodb: match documents without substring in array field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I'm trying to match documents without a substring in an array field, in an aggregation pipeline.

I believe I need to add a field and then do a `$match` on `-1`, but I'm stuck on `$indexOfBytes` to find substrings in an array field.

```js
db.collectionName.aggregate([{$addFields:{indexOfA:{$indexOfBytes:['$arrayName.fieldName1.fieldName2','A']}}}])
```

I get the error:

```
MongoServerError: PlanExecutor error during aggregation :: caused by :: $indexOfBytes requires a string as the first argument, found: array
```

collection example:

```json
[
  { arrayName: [ fieldName1: { fieldName2: 'A' } ] },
  { arrayName: [ fieldName1: { fieldName2: 'B' } ] },
  { arrayName: [ fieldName1: { fieldName2: 'C' } ] },
  { arrayName: [ ] }
]
```

desired result (:

```json
[
  { arrayName: [ fieldName1: { fieldName2: 'B' } ] },
  { arrayName: [ fieldName1: { fieldName2: 'C' } ] },
  { arrayName: [ ] }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 $addFields: {
  arrayName: {
    "$filter": {
      "input": "$arrayName",
      "as": "a",
      "cond": {
        $eq: [
          {
            $indexOfBytes: [
              "$$a.fieldName1.fieldName2",
              "A"
            ]
          },
          -1
        ]
      }
     }
    }
   }
  },
  {
   $match: {
    $expr: {
     $ne: [
       {
         $size: "$arrayName"
       },
       0
     ]
    }
   }
  }
 ])
```

Explained:

1. $filter arrayName elements not having A in fieldName2
2. $match only the non-empty arrayName arrays

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/uClf2AV-F-4)

Comment: does this work when `arrayName` is empty?  as in, is that document included?

Comment: was able to include them with `{$eq: [{$size: "$arrayName"}, {$size: "$arrayNameWithoutA"}]}` and adding the field `arrayNameWithoutA` instead of replacing `arrayName`